# spring-context-indexer with Swagger 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have a maven multimodule java 11 project.
The project is configured with Swagger 3

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As soon as I add spring-context-indexer as dependency in all maven modules the swagger ui is not working anymore

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
     <optional>true</optional>
 </dependency>
```

[image: Swagger error]

If I remove the spring-context-indexer dependency from all maven modules, the swagger ui works.

How can I solve this issue? (we use spring security if this matters)

Comment: I think this issue was not solved until now :( => https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2451

Comment: Springfox is dead =(

Answer (score -1):

sometimes the last version of a dependency may have some compatibility issues with other dependencies.
**try a older version.**

Comment: Swagger-context-indexer have this problem with all versions of swagger