# Disable spring-context-indexer by profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I want to enable [Spring Context Indexer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-index) on a project but I am having issues with Swagger3 (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043455/spring-context-indexer-with-swagger-3) and [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2451)).

I understand the limitations and would like to enable it, at least, at the DEV profile where we do not need Swagger running.

My goal is to disable indexing on PROD environment. From [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-index):

```
you can fallback to a regular classpath arrangement (as though no index was present at all) by setting spring.index.ignore to true, either as a system property or in a spring.properties file at the root of the classpath.
```

My first approach (without success) was setting an env var (Windows 10) with the following:

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"spring":{"index":{"ignore":true}}}
```

If I create a spring.properties file and set the value accordingly it works. But I can't figure how to use different properties for each profile, I imagined it was something like the application.properties file but I was wrong.

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, this config (spring.index.ignore) will just work if inside a **spring.properties** file, not an **application.properties** one. (Just double-checked before this edit)

Actually I have one application-prod.properties and one application-dev.properties.

I don't know the difference between spring.properties and application.properties but the first one doesn't seem to work with multiple profiles as the later.

Edit 2:

Just went through *org.springframework.context.index.CandidateComponentsIndexLoader* and it uses **SpringProperties.getFlag(IGNORE_INDEX)** to read the value.

SpringProperties class is clear about the file it uses:

```
Reads a spring.properties file from the root of the Spring library classpath, and also allows for programmatically setting properties through setProperty. When checking a property, local entries are being checked first, then falling back to JVM-level system properties through a System.getProperty check.
```

I think I will need to pass a property to Java runner during initialization. Will research a little bit more about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use different application.properties file as follow:

add the following files to the resource folder:

application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev #place profile name you want to use
```

application-dev.properties

```
#dev properties
...
```

You can create many application-env.properties you may wish

application-env.properties

```
#env properties
...
```

Comment: The config needs to be inside a spring.properties file, not an application.properties one. I just edited my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot supports profile-specific properties files. You have to name these files with the following format: application-{profile}.properties. You can activate a profile via JVM system parameter: -Dspring.profiles.active=dev. You can read more about this subject here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: The config needs to be inside a spring.properties file, not an application.properties one. I just edited my question to be clearer.